# Delta method for $\bar X$^2

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, asymptotics, delta-method

I have a question about the delta method. The question is:

$X_1,...,X_n \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, where $\sigma^2=V(x)$ and $\mu=E(X)$ let T=$\bar X^2$ be an estimate for $\mu^2$. Find the asymptotic distribution for $\sqrt{n}(T-\mu^2)$ based on the delta theorem when $\mu\neq 0$

My answer would be:

The CLT states that:

$$\sqrt{n}(\bar X-\mu) \rightarrow N(0,\sigma^2)$$

This implies that:

$$\sqrt{n}(h(T)-h(\mu)) \rightarrow N(0,(h'(\mu))^2\sigma^2)$$
where $h(\mu)= \mu^2$, and we therefore get:

$$h'(\mu)^2= (2\mu)^2=4\mu^2$$

Thus, we end up with:

$$\sqrt{n}(\bar X^2-\mu^2) \rightarrow N(0,4\mu^2\sigma^2)$$

I am not sure however that I grasp the concept correctly. Can anyone give look at it and let me know what you think.

Also, I need to find the asymptotic distribution of nT when $\mu=0$ and I am not sure how to do that. Any tips on how to get started? To me it seems obvious that by the CLT we get:

$$\sqrt{n}(\bar X) \rightarrow N(0,\sigma^2)$$

However, I am not sure how to move forward from here.

Lastly, the questions asks me to find the limiting laws of $\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu)^2$ and $n(\bar X - \mu)^2$, not sure how to start on that either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your work for $\mu\ne 0$ looks correct. Now when $\mu=0$, what is the limiting distribution (in this case also the exact distribution) of $n\overline X^2=(\sqrt n\overline X)^2$ when you know $\sqrt n\overline X\to N(0,\sigma^2)$ in distribution?

Comment: Ye that's the problems, I am not sure since there is $h(\mu)$ I am not sure that to multiply the variance with? Intuitively I would say that since it is squared, it should be $\chi^2$ distributed.

Comment: As long as the $X_i$'s are i.i.d normal, $n\overline X^2$ has an exact $\chi^2$ distribution (scaled appropriately) because $\sqrt n \overline X \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. Even if they were not normal, this would have been the asymptotic distribution by [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem).

Comment: In the case of $\mu=0$, you need to expand the Taylor Series out one more term.  Since $h^{\prime}(0)=0$ and $h^{\prime \prime}(0)=2$, you have the approximation $\sqrt{n} \left(h(\bar{X})-h(\mu)\right) = \sqrt{n}\left(\bar{x}-\mu\right)^2$.